# How to create set of simple entries uniqe id json python

Tags: python, json

I am attempting to create a simple python app which would store a simple set of data in a json format python. I have been struggling with this issue for days literally. What I am trying to do is the following:

```
import json  
student = {"101":{"class":'V', "Name":'Rohit',  "Roll_no":7},  
           "102":{"class":'X', "Name":'David',  "Roll_no":8},  
           "103":{"class":'Z', "Name":'Samiya', "Roll_no":12}}
```

I could not find how to do smth like that: for example 
I wann add :

```
"104":{"class":'Z', "Name":'Jans', "Roll_no":15}


student = {"101":{"class":'V', "Name":'Rohit',  "Roll_no":7},  
           "102":{"class":'X', "Name":'David',  "Roll_no":8},  
           "103":{"class":'Z', "Name":'Samiya', "Roll_no":12}
           "104":{"class":'Z', "Name":'Jans', "Roll_no":15}}
```

Could somebody please explain to me how to ADD,DELETE,REPLACE, 
entries organized in json python file. It would be nice to figure out 
the way of ORDER BY,SORT for e.g. "class" field or any other parameter similarly to MySQL ORDER BY command.

I found thousands of links however I am still lost.

Thx. I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Are you talking about JSON or Python dictionaries? They're different, they just happen to have similar syntaxes. It's not clear whether you have the data in a Python module or in a JSON file.

Comment: Well I am working in python I just found out that json would be an efficient way to store the type of data I need to work with. If you have any suggestions to avoid json and using only dict I am all for it. I certainly want to keep my data in python module.

Comment: You use dictionaries in python code, once you are done with your work you can transform it to JSON and write it to a file. see [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [JSON library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). N.B. these links are for python2 but you should easily find the corresponding docs for python3

Comment: Sorry, but this did not help me. I went through this pages many times. I do not know to create this kind of structure by my own. It's miserable.

Comment: @user2156115: When loading the data from a file, you convert the file content *from* JSON *to* a Python dictionary. When saving the data to disk, you convert it back and write it to a file. However, I recommend you skip JSON for now and just learn more about how Python works, because it shows that you lack understanding of some basic concepts.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure that you are using, isn't a JSON, is a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

```
>>> student = {
    "101":{"class":'V', "Name":'Rohit',  "Roll_no":7},
    "102":{"class":'X', "Name":'David',  "Roll_no":8},
    "103":{"class":'Z', "Name":'Samiya', "Roll_no":12}
}
```

Get data from `student` use `get`

```
>>> print student["101"]
{'class': 'V', 'Roll_no': 7, 'Name': 'Rohit'}
```

Delete an entry from dict removing an unwanted key

```
>>> del  student["101"]
{'102': {'Name': 'David', 'Roll_no': 8, 'class': 'X'},
 '103': {'Name': 'Samiya', 'Roll_no': 12, 'class': 'Z'}}
```

Add and replace entries from dict are similar. To replace, select which key you want and change it's value. To add, just add a new key, value pair to existent `dict`

**Replace**

```
>>> student["101"] = {'Name': 'Johnny', 'Roll_no': 9, 'class': 'S'},
>>> print student
student = {
        "101":{'Name': 'Johnny', 'Roll_no': 9, 'class': 'S'},
        "102":{"class":'X', "Name":'David',  "Roll_no":8},
        "103":{"class":'Z', "Name":'Samiya', "Roll_no":12}
}
```

**Add**

```
>>> student["104"] = {'Name': 'Johnny', 'Roll_no': 9, 'class': 'S'},
>>> print student
student = {
        "101":{"class":'V', "Name":'Rohit',  "Roll_no":7},
        "102":{"class":'X', "Name":'David',  "Roll_no":8},
        "103":{"class":'Z', "Name":'Samiya', "Roll_no":12},
        "104":{"class":'S', "Name":'Johnny', "Roll_no":9},
}
```

By default, dictionaries are not ordered, but Python has [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) that may help you.

Comment: Thanks Mauro, that seems to be a reasonable solution. I just need to get use to OrderdDict. Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

In the first place I wanna thank you for each of your suggestions. They shaped my solution more or less. Nevertheless, I have got my **final solution** and I guess it could help the others as well.

Let's see:

**CREATE DICT:**

```
>>> student = {}
>>>
>>> names =['jano','tibor','petka','jozi','timea','lenka','monika','fero']
>>> roll = [i for i in xrange(8)]
>>> for i,j,k in zip(xrange(8),names,roll):
...    student[i] = {'Name': j, 'Roll_no': k, 'class': 'S'}
```

***result of a previous step:***

```
>>> student
{0: {'Name': 'jano', 'Roll_no': 0, 'class': 'S'}, 1: {'Name': 'tibor', 'Roll_no': 1, 'class': 'S'}, 2: {'Name': 'petka', 'Roll_no': 2, 'class': 'S'}, 3: {'Name': 'jozi', 'Roll_no': 3, 'class': 'S'}, 4: {'Name': 'timea', 'Roll_no': 4, 'class': 'S'}, 5: {'Name': 'lenka', 'Roll_no': 5, 'class': 'S'}, 6: {'Name': 'monika', 'Roll_no': 6, 'class': 'S'}, 7: {'Name': 'fero', 'Roll_no': 7, 'class': 'S'}}





>>> for i,j in student.items():
...    print i,j
...
0 {'Name': 'jano', 'Roll_no': 0, 'class': 'S'}
1 {'Name': 'tibor', 'Roll_no': 1, 'class': 'S'}
2 {'Name': 'petka', 'Roll_no': 2, 'class': 'S'}
3 {'Name': 'jozi', 'Roll_no': 3, 'class': 'S'}
4 {'Name': 'timea', 'Roll_no': 4, 'class': 'S'}
5 {'Name': 'lenka', 'Roll_no': 5, 'class': 'S'}
6 {'Name': 'monika', 'Roll_no': 6, 'class': 'S'}
7 {'Name': 'fero', 'Roll_no': 7, 'class': 'S'}
```

... ok that's awesome .. that's what I wanted ..

**PRINTING DESIRED COLUMNS:**

```
>>> for i,j in student.items():
...        print j['Name'],j['Roll_no']
...
jano 0
tibor 1
petka 2
jozi 3
timea 4
lenka 5
monika 6
fero 7
```

**Using some conditions:**

```
>>> for i,j in student.items():
...    if j['Name'] == "monika":
...       print i,j
...
6 {'Name': 'monika', 'Roll_no': 6, 'class': 'S'}
```

**SORTING by column - IMPORTANT**

all the values are basically sorted by "Roll_no" column !!!!

```
from collections import OrderedDict

>>> c=OrderedDict(sorted(student.items(),key=lambda (x,y): y['Roll_no']))
>>> for i,j in c.items(): print i,j
...
0 {'Name': 'jano', 'Roll_no': 0, 'class': 'S'}
1 {'Name': 'tibor', 'Roll_no': 1, 'class': 'S'}
2 {'Name': 'petka', 'Roll_no': 2, 'class': 'S'}
3 {'Name': 'jozi', 'Roll_no': 3, 'class': 'S'}
5 {'Name': 'lenka', 'Roll_no': 5, 'class': 'S'}
6 {'Name': 'monika', 'Roll_no': 6, 'class': 'S'}
7 {'Name': 'fero', 'Roll_no': 7, 'class': 'S'}
4 {'Name': 'timea', 'Roll_no': 8, 'class': 'S'}
```

**REPLACE 'Roll_no': 8   to 'Roll_no': 12**

```
>>> student[4] = {'Name': 'timea', 'Roll_no': 12, 'class': 'S'}
>>> for i,j in student.items(): print i,j
...
0 {'Name': 'jano', 'Roll_no': 0, 'class': 'S'}
1 {'Name': 'tibor', 'Roll_no': 1, 'class': 'S'}
2 {'Name': 'petka', 'Roll_no': 2, 'class': 'S'}
3 {'Name': 'jozi', 'Roll_no': 3, 'class': 'S'}
4 {'Name': 'timea', 'Roll_no': 12, 'class': 'S'}
5 {'Name': 'lenka', 'Roll_no': 5, 'class': 'S'}
6 {'Name': 'monika', 'Roll_no': 6, 'class': 'S'}
7 {'Name': 'fero', 'Roll_no': 7, 'class': 'S'}
```

**DELETTING particular entry:**

```
del student[7]
```